# How to the particles leave the dees in a cyclotron?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I'm confused that, in the working of a cyclotron, the particles enter and leave the dees. But how can they do so? Particles like protons, can't enter or leave a metallic body as per their wish.
image - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotron#/media/File:Cyclotron_diagram.png

Answer (score 2):

Each time after the particles pass to the other dee electrode the polarity of the voltage reverses. Therefore, each time the particles cross the gap from one dee electrode to the other, the electric field is in the correct direction to accelerate them. The particles' increasing speed due to these pushes causes them to move in a larger radius circle with each rotation, so the particles move in a spiral path outward from the center to the rim of the dees. When they reach the rim a small voltage on a metal plate deflects the beam so it exits the dees through a small gap between them, and hits a target located at the exit point at the rim of the chamber, or leaves the cyclotron through an evacuated beam tube to hit a remote target.

For details check : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotron

Comment: +1 for the lucid explanation without much technical jargon. But perhaps you can enhance it by some equations like in EigenFunction's Answer. :)

Comment: Why don't they feel any electric field inside a dee. The reason can't be Faraday's cage/Electrostatic  shielding because in this image the dees are not full shells. They have one open side.

Answer (score 1):

As they travel within the cyclotron, the particles are accelerated by an alternating potential difference applied across the dees. Hence they gain kinetic energy as they travel between the dees. From $F=\frac{mv^2}{r}$ and $F=qvB$, we get $r=\frac{mv}{qB}$ and hence the radius of the path travelled increases with the velocity of the particles. Hence at a certain velocity the radius is large enough that the particles leave the dees.

Comment: Why don't they feel any electric field inside a dee. The reason can't be Faraday's cage/Electrostatic  shielding because in this image the dees are not full shells. They have one open side.